# accessing outer shell variables inside nawk in ksh

Tags: shell, unix, awk, ksh, nawk

I am trying to access a shell variable inside a piped nawk.
I have never done this before and was wondering if its possible.

Here is the command `sbdadm list-lu` contents:

> Found 2 LU(s)
>
> ```
>           GUID                    DATA SIZE           SOURCE
> ```
>
> ---
>
> 600144f029bf0a0000004e0484740052 
>   107380964864         /dev/rdsk/c9d0s1
>   600144f029bf0a0000004e0484740053 
>   53694562304          /dev/rdsk/c9d0s3

Here is my sample of my script :

```
DISK=/dev/rdsk/c9d0s3
sbdadm list-lu |nawk '/$DISK/ {print}'
```

**NOTE**: I know the " `/$DISK/`" syntax will not work since $ is part of a regex symbol.
I need the right syntax if such a code is ever possible.

In addition,does awk spawn another shell?
 If so, is it possible that I can export this variable `$DISK` to that shell.

Comment: Are you aware that the `cat output` is a [UUOC](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/U/UUOC.html)?

Comment: @larsmans : sorry abt the typo.. corrected

Comment: `echo` won't work. See my answer.

Comment: @larsman: Sorry about the confusion ... basically I wanted sbdadm list-lu> output .... got confused about output being a variable instead of a file ... I have re-corrected the question .. Thanks for the help  you guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not that `$` is part of RE syntax; it's that `/` is the RE delimiter. If you were just looking for `c9d0s3`, then using the proper quoting would do the trick:

```
$ DISK=c9d0s3
$ awk "/$DISK/ {print}" output
600144f029bf0a0000004e0484740053 53694562304 /dev/rdsk/c9d0s3
```

Explanation: if you use `""` instead of `''`, then the shell variable would be expanded *before* handing the program to `awk`, so `awk` would see

```
/c9d0s3/ {print}
```

as its program. You can still search for a pattern with `/` in it, but it takes some shell quoting magic:

```
$ DISK=/dev/rdsk/c9d0s3
$ awk "{if (match(\$0, \"$DISK\")) print}" output
600144f029bf0a0000004e0484740053 53694562304 /dev/rdsk/c9d0s3
```

And no, `awk` does not spawn a subshell. Why would it? And why would you need one to pass a variable if you can just do it through the environment?

Comment: Since single quotes dint do the trick for me .. I assumed that the only reason $DISK wasnt visible was coz it was in another shell...Thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 1):

```
export DISK=/dev/rdsk/c9d0s3
cat output | awk '$0 ~ ENVIRON["DISK"]{print}'
```

results:

```
600144f029bf0a0000004e0484740053 53694562304 /dev/rdsk/c9d0s3
```

With `system` call (after DISK was exported):

`echo | awk '{system("echo $DISK")}'`

results:

`/dev/rdsk/c9d0s3`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [j.w.r's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6472653/accessing-outer-shell-variables-inside-nawk-in-ksh/6472845#6472845), you can explicitly set an awk variable with the value of the shell variable:

```
 nawk -v disk="$DISK" '$3 == disk' output_file
```